# JavaFX 8 screen rendering freezes when running with hw acceleration enabled

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

One of our JavaFX 8 freezes quite frequently when running on Microsoft Surface 3, every now and then when running on a different tablet running Windows 8 and once in a blue moon when running on a normal desktop.

If we run it with `prism.order=sw`, it doesn't freeze but the performance on tablets is a little bit too slow to be usable.

When it the screen freezes, one can still click on the screen and all events and the JavaFX thread appear to be working as usual but it just seems that the prism / quantum rendering or whatever it is that it actually converts the scenegraph to pixels crashed.

I've reported a bug in the old JIRA and new JBS and apparently we need to produce a reproducible test case which we don't have time to prepare.

Any ideas as to why this can be happening? Anyone has had this happening  as well? Any hints as to how to get to the root of the problem?

Comment: What java version is used on the different environments?

Comment: One possible reason is if you do some JavaFX "stuff" outside the JavaFX thread.

Comment: @hotzst 8u60 across the board